# How to copy the docker images to IBM zCX server from USS

Tags: docker, installation, websphere, workflow, mainframe

I am trying to build z/OSMF workflow to copy my application docker images from USS into zCX server. There are two approaches -

1. Push docker image to zCX Private/Public docker Registry.
2. Copy the docker tar to ZCX and load into docker repository using docker load command

I have neither zCX Docker Registry nor a linux system. My docker images are available in tar format on USS. There is no SFTP available in zCX.

1. Is there any way to get my docker images in zCX?
2. Is there any z/OSMF built-in step to perform this activity?

I read the documentation - http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248457.pdf. It is not so clear to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up zCX, and set up a default userid, then presumably you can ssh from USS env in zOS to the zCX env, with no pwd requried.

Which means you can do cmd like this to binary transfer a file to zCX

ZCX @ SC:/tmp>echo 'put  /tmp/hw.txt' | sftp -P 8022 admin@cn02.ibm.com:/tmp

The authenticity of host '[cn02.ibm.com]:8022 ([129.01.01.01]:8022)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:CplCw7We+4b/gOK8ngj9XlY3p6uFNZXRabmvBqu6r3o.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
FOTS2274 Warning: Permanently added '[cn02.ibm.com]:8022,[129.01.01.01]:8022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connected to cn02.ibm.com.
Changing to: /tmp
sftp> put  /tmp/hw.txt
Uploading /tmp/hw.txt to /tmp/hw.txt
/tmp/hw.txt                                                                           100%   20     0.0KB/s   00:00

In zCX, when logon:

admin@cn02:/tmp$ pwd
/tmp
admin@cn02:/tmp$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 admin admin 20 May 15 12:37 hw.txt
admin@cn02:/tmp$ cat hw.txt
ȅ▒▒▒@▒▒▒▒@▒▒▒@z`]admin@cn02:/tmp$

As SFTP does binary transfer by default, the contents of the hw.txt file which are EBCDIC in USS, have been transferred as is to zCX

As zCX is ASCII, when you do cat on hw.txt in zCX get unreadable output, since the ASCII env is trying to output data that is EBCDIC

As you want to transfer a tar file from USS to zCX, you do no want EBCDIC to ASCII conversion to happen, you want sftp to do asis ( binary transfer ) , which is the default

Comment: Are you confirming that SFTPD is available in zCX SSH container?  I can't confirm, our zCX trial is over. Team is working on getting one setup. 

Is there any documentation reference about SFTPD?

For ASCII files, there needs to be some facility in zCX to convert the enconding e.g iconv.

Answer (score 0):

There is sftp in zcx

After I logged into zCX, did sftp cmd and got:

```
admin@cn02:~$ sftp
usage: sftp [-46aCfpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
      [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
      [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
      [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
   sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
   sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
   sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```

Comment: I am trying to deploy my docker images using z/oSMF workflow in automated way. I was wondering if I could SFTP a docker tar from USS to zCX. What you are showing me is sftp client in the zCX. I am not clear, how can it help me get my docker images in zCX through workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the original question 2 above - there currently is no z/OSMF workflow to upload tarballs of images.  It is an interesting idea though.  Push/pull from a registry is the more common way of moving images around.

You may want to consider staying in touch with a project called Zorrow at the Open Mainframe project (https://www.openmainframeproject.org/projects/zorow).  We're in the early stages of creating a community there where people would share this kind of a workflow.

Comment: Appreciate your response. zCX being new technology, our customers do not have lot of expertise on docker registry yet. This is chicken and egg problem. We are thinking of deploying docker registry or docker tarballs using z/oSMF workflows..  Logged an issue/enhancement request https://github.com/openmainframeproject/zorow/issues